# how to sort records of a column in jasper report

Tags: java, xml, sorting, jasper-reports

I am working on Jasper ireport tool. I am getting records from table, but I wanted to sort the records. Whether I have to do sorting in java code or we can do it in tool itself I am not getting. so please help me how i can sort. Thank you in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Myreport" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="535" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="7a6aa9cf-834e-4433-bf00-09da542cedcf">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <style name="Title" forecolor="#FFFFFF" fontName="Times New Roman" fontSize="50" isBold="false" pdfFontName="Times-Bold"/>
    <style name="SubTitle" forecolor="#CCCCCC" fontName="Times New Roman" fontSize="18" isBold="false" pdfFontName="Times-Roman"/>
    <style name="Column header" forecolor="#666666" fontName="Times New Roman" fontSize="14" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Times-Roman"/>
    <style name="Detail" mode="Transparent" fontName="Times New Roman" pdfFontName="Times-Roman"/>
    <style name="Row" mode="Transparent" fontName="Times New Roman" pdfFontName="Times-Roman">
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}%2 == 0]]></conditionExpression>
            <style mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0EFEF"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
    </style>
    <queryString language="SQL">
        <![CDATA[select * from ireport;]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="Username" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="Empnumber" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="dept" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="organisation" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="Designation" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="dateOfCreation" class="java.sql.Date">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <sortField name="Username"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="132" splitType="Stretch">
            <frame>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="451" height="95" backcolor="#000000" uuid="2936018d-2b8a-4dc5-9cd1-f40670680e7f"/>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement style="Title" x="0" y="0" width="370" height="66" uuid="f1a20926-1f5e-4b58-aca4-443c2693a2d9"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font isBold="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[COGXAR]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement style="SubTitle" x="157" y="66" width="249" height="29" uuid="f3292300-bafd-40a9-bed3-e60684e263a1"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="22" isBold="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Cogxarian]]></text>
                </staticText>
            </frame>
            <frame>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="100" width="451" height="32" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#CC0000" uuid="3f5100f2-6886-440b-b495-428750dd9274"/>
                <textField pattern="EEEEE dd MMMMM yyyy">
                    <reportElement x="307" y="12" width="144" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="1cafc436-89d2-4ca3-b1a4-41b6a5f1d684"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                        <font size="12"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="26" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="Column header" x="0" y="7" width="92" height="18" forecolor="#000000" uuid="c663f7b2-b7b7-493a-822d-72ad6b74d24a"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Username]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="Column header" x="92" y="7" width="92" height="18" forecolor="#000000" uuid="f550db3a-3e20-4955-8197-fa0b71f95ac0"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Empnumber]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="Column header" x="184" y="7" width="92" height="18" forecolor="#000000" uuid="0f22eeff-a2ba-4e2f-8c7e-087305844079"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[dept]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="Column header" x="276" y="7" width="92" height="18" forecolor="#000000" uuid="050a8043-0089-4496-8cf7-80aeca305866"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[organisation]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="Column header" x="368" y="7" width="92" height="18" forecolor="#000000" uuid="ca99e045-3117-425f-b918-57fac68acc13"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Designation]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="Column header" x="460" y="7" width="92" height="18" forecolor="#000000" uuid="88f8eb45-00ae-476e-a4a7-d451fff93608"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[dateOfCreation]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="18" splitType="Stretch">
            <frame>
                <reportElement style="Row" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="555" height="18" uuid="0105b77c-fd98-4b2e-9b1a-229de1e56889"/>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                    <reportElement style="Detail" positionType="Float" x="0" y="0" width="92" height="18" uuid="5b41779b-5b12-4843-be95-c2092e86859b"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="14"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Username}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                    <reportElement style="Detail" positionType="Float" x="92" y="0" width="92" height="18" uuid="0a87e452-d44b-463e-9e29-67934e9561db"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="14"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Empnumber}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                    <reportElement style="Detail" positionType="Float" x="184" y="0" width="92" height="18" uuid="a669140e-e1b8-4dad-8821-9ddb2b1d4c7d"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="14"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{dept}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                    <reportElement style="Detail" positionType="Float" x="276" y="0" width="92" height="18" uuid="c4cb3a09-f100-4c53-898a-9513decc43be"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="14"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{organisation}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                    <reportElement style="Detail" positionType="Float" x="368" y="0" width="92" height="18" uuid="de6e6deb-6a26-4ee0-9dd4-e11f446e1d56"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="14"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Designation}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                    <reportElement style="Detail" positionType="Float" x="460" y="0" width="92" height="18" uuid="a4dd4dd7-682b-43f2-80f6-d84eea5fd001"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="14"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{dateOfCreation}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="142" splitType="Stretch">
            <line>
                <reportElement positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" x="0" y="3" width="555" height="1" uuid="d472bee8-7d59-46f2-a9ca-1adad4b8f0f9"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#999999"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
        </band>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="160" splitType="Stretch">
            <frame>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="1" width="555" height="24" forecolor="#D0B48E" backcolor="#000000" uuid="53c76dd1-ef10-49a4-a80c-729f04a2b5aa"/>
                <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                    <reportElement style="Column header" x="513" y="0" width="40" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="390b5016-5c20-479f-9aee-40b0ba966798"/>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font size="10" isBold="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement style="Column header" x="433" y="0" width="80" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="1ee577c5-d775-4b82-a3c5-c28b48fe5b8b"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font size="10" isBold="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Page "+$V{PAGE_NUMBER}+" of"]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField pattern="EEEEE dd MMMMM yyyy">
                    <reportElement style="Column header" x="2" y="1" width="197" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="4272ffa9-1561-453a-b52c-9f2415d9583a"/>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font size="10" isBold="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: can you adjust your sql ? select * from ireport order by column_name

Answer (score 3):

you will find a "sort" element in your iReport Designer palette.

You can drag this element into your report layout (for example, in a header row), and you will see a toggling arrow (which can sort ascending or descending).

After adding this sort option to your report, select it, and navigate to its "properties".

In this view, you can assign a column to it, and other properties like styles, etc.

When you run the report and click on the arrow, it will sort the report's data based on the column you selected, and the direction (ascending or descending).

From : [Jasper Wiki](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/there-simple-way-add-fieldcolumn-sorting-jrxml-report)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the

```
<sr:sort>
```

element to sort based on a field.

```
<reportelement height="20" width="30" >
    <sr:sort sortfieldname="field_to_sort"
        sortfieldtype="Field"
        xmlns:sr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components"
        xsi:schemalocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components"/>  
</reportelement>
```

You can use iReport Designer for doing this easily. IReport is a gui based designer for creating jasper reports.

Jasper reports, Table component also provides many interactive features like sorting.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure, but if you have a look at IReportDesigner (the official tool for creating .jrxml files) there is an option in tutorial 'group by'. And if that's not working I think IReportDesigner is the tool to achieve what you need anyway.